# RMarkdown: Euro symbol not shown on ggplot geom_text and axis text when knitting to PDF

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

I use RStudio 2023.03.01 on Linux Mint (Debian edition bullseye/11.2) to write some reports in r-markdown.
When the rendering in RStudio is done, the € symbol is shown on the gglot2 plots.
But when I knit the rmd file to a PDF report, the € symbol is only shown as ...

```
df %>% filter(Umsatz > 0 & Wer != "") %>% 
  group_by(Wer) %>% 
  summarise(Einnahmen = sum(Umsatz)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Wer, y=Einnahmen, fill=Wer)) +
    geom_col(fill=c('darkblue', 'darkred', 'orange'), width=0.7) +
    ggtitle('Einnahmen') + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = human_euro) +
    geom_text(aes(label=scales::comma(Einnahmen, big.mark = '.', decimal.mark = ',', prefix = '€ ')), vjust=-0.1, color="black", size=5) +
    theme_foundation(base_size = 16, base_family = 'sans') +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20)) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 16)) +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image: Inside RStudio]
[image: After knitting to PDF]

RStudio uses `pandoc` and `pdflatex` for generating the PDF.
When executing `locale` it reports that the settings are `en_GB.UTF-8`.

What can I do to get the € symbol into the PDF?

Comment: Try using unicode for the EU currency. Possibly "\u20AC". You may need to check the unicode on line.

Comment: @Peter unfortunately this did not help.

Comment: @Joysn Do you have this problem with xelatex too?

Comment: @manro When I verify the figures which are created each as PDF in the XYZ_files filder, they lack the Euro symbol. The TeX file then includes them to create the final PDF with Pandoc/xelatex.

Comment: @Joysn Which LaTeX distro do you use?

Comment: @manro `texlive` version `2020.20210202-3` on Debian 11.2